# why this code is not calling Matlab function

Tags: c, matlab, octave, mex

I have written a code in MATLAB to add two numbers. The code is given below:

```
function [z] = addition(x,y)
    z=x+y;
end
```

I have written another code in C to call this addition function. The code is given below:

```
#include "mex.h"

void  mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[],
      int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
    mxArray *a,*b,*c;
    a=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
    b=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
    a=1;
    b=1;
    mexCallMATLAB(1,&c, 2, &b, &a, "addition");
    mexCallMATLAB(0,NULL,1, &c, "disp");
    mxDestroyArray(a);
    mxDestroyArray(b);

    return;
}
```

please tell me why it is not working???
thanks

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: Your code has this line 'mexCallMATLAB(1,&c, 2, &b, &a, "addition");'. mexCallMATLAB should have an array of pointers for the input, not 2 separate input pointers.

Comment: yes, that and you must get pointer to data of the `mxArray` (`mxGetPr`/`mxGetData`) before you assign values into it. Since you are dealing with scalars, you could just use `mxCreateDoubleScalar` as I did below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the code:

- The way you assign values to the mxArray's `a` and `b` is incorrect.
- the way you pass the inputs to `mexCallMATLAB` is also not correct

Here is my implementation:

#### callAdd.c

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mxArray *in[2], *out[1];

    in[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(5);
    in[1] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(4);

    mexCallMATLAB(1, out, 2, in, "addition");
    mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 1, out, "disp");

    mxDestroyArray(in[0]);
    mxDestroyArray(in[1]);
    mxDestroyArray(out[0]);
}
```

This is basically equivalent to calling `disp(addition(5,4))` in MATLAB

Comment: you solved my problem thanks . i just want to know one more thing about mxArray. mxArray is for input and output argument. why dont we use  `mxArray *in[1],*in[0], *out[0];` ?

Comment: MATLAB represents all variable using the opaque type `mxArray` (including scalars, vectors, matrices, structs, cell arrays, etc..). In the code above, `in` is defined as an array of two `mxArray` pointers. Perhaps it would help if you read a C tutorial on pointers and arrays.